# multiple audio html using embed tag and javascript : auto stop others when current is playing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am using embed tag for playing videos.
Issue is when I press Next button followed by Previous button quickly(with in ~2 sec), both next and previous audio/video starts playing simultaneously but if I click  Next button followed by Previous button  after long duration (~ 10 second ), it works perfectly fine.

The code I have written is :

```
$.each($('embed'), function() {
    if(this.id == 'wmvFile_'+itemId) {  
        if($('#wmvFile_' + itemId).length) {
            var parent = $('#wmvFile_' + itemId).parent();
            $('#wmvFile_' + itemId).remove();
            var newElement = "<embed autostart='true' allowfullscreen='true' style='width:100%; height:100%;' src='" + url + "'id='wmvFile_" + itemId + "'>";
            parent.append(newElement);
        }
    }
    else {                    
        if($(this.id.indexOf("wmvFile_") != -1).length) {                        
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(this).remove();
            var newElement = "<embed autostart='false' src='about:blank' allowfullscreen='true' style='width:100%; height:100%;' id= '" + this.id + "'>";
            parent.append(newElement);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Play first video, then if user clicks a 'Next' button, then it should stop and the second video should start playing?

Comment: @nichlas900 : Yes..